# Django changing pdf font's xhtml2pdf

Tags: django, pdf, fonts, render

So i am rendering an object to pdf and i want to change my pdf font.

**My project**

```html
myproject/
     |-- myproject
     |-- static/
          |-- admin/
            |-- fonts/
              |-- GothamPro-Medium.eot
              |-- GothamPro-Medium.ttf
              |-- GothamPro-Medium.woff
              |-- GothamPro-Medium.woff2
```

**my page.html**

```html
<style type="text/css">
             @page {
                size: A4;
            }
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'GothamPro-Medium';
                src: url('static/admin/fonts/GothamPro-Medium.woff') format('woff'),
                     url('static/admin/fonts/GothamPro-Medium.woff2') format('woff2'),
                     url('static/admin/fonts/GothamPro-Medium.eot?') format('eot'),
                     url('static/admin/fonts/GothamPro-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
            }               
            body {
                font-family: 'GothamPro-Medium';

            }
</style>
<body>
TESTE
</body>
```

My font is not working , i already try it with another font's and nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add setting.py following here

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

then in template
add this to the top of html file

```
{% load static %}
```

and use 
`url({% static 'admin/fonts/GothamPro-Medium.ttf' %})` instead `url('static/admin/fonts/GothamPro-Medium.ttf')`

Answer (score 1):

Use /static/admin/fonts/GothamPro-Medium.woff